# How to adapt Javascript dropdown addition with Javascript AJAX database retrieved data?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I currently have a line with 2 dropdowns and the first dropdown affects what's inside the second dropdown using AJAX javascript : `Room Types > Rooms of that type`

And I have AJAX javascript to add another line of `Room types > rooms`.

But what happens is that when I add another line of dropdowns, when I change the value of the very first dropdown on the first line it affects all of the subsequent dropdowns on the other lines.

Picture of the dropdowns with the first dropdown affecting all other dropdowns:

[image]

How do I make it that the added dropdowns also affect the ones right next to it?

create.blade.php (Javascript AJAX code for retrieving info from database):

```
    $('select[name="type"]').on('change', function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        if(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/myform/ajax/'+id,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                    $('select[name="rooms_id[]"]').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="rooms_id[]"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('select[name="rooms_id[]"]').empty();
        }
    });
```

in the same file - AJAX code for adding the dropdown list:

```
    $('.add1').click(function () {
        var n = ($('.resultbody1 tr').length - 0) + 1;
        var tr = '<tr><td class="no">' + n + '</td>' +
                '<td> <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id="type" name = "type"> @foreach($roomtypes as $p)<option value="{{$p['id']}}">{{ $p['room_type']}}</option>@endforeach</select></div></td>' +
                '<td><div class="form-group"><select class="form-control" id="room" name = "rooms_id[]" style="width:300px" ></select></div></td>' +
                '<td><input class="input" name="price" id="price" type="text" value="-" readonly></td>' +
                '<td><div class="form-group row"><div class="col-10"><input class="form-control" type="number" value="0" id="example-number-input" name="pax"></div></div></td>'+
                '<td><span id="amount"></span></td>'+
                '<td><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger delete" value="x"></td></tr>';
        $('.resultbody1').append(tr);
    });
    $('.resultbody1').delegate('.delete', 'click', function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

HTML code from the same code:

```
<td>
                                         <div class="form-group">
                                            <select class="form-control" id="type" name = "type" >
                                            @foreach($roomtypes as $p)
                                                <option value="{{$p['id']}}">{{ $p['room_type']}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <select class="form-control" id="room" name = "rooms_id[]" style="width:300px" >
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
```

>

Controller codes:

```
 public function myform()
    {
        $type = DB::table("room_types")
                ->pluck("room_type","id");
        return view('myform',compact('type'));
    }

public function myformAjax($id)
{
    $room = Room::get()
                ->where("room_types_id",$id)
                ->pluck("room_number","id");
    return json_encode($room);
}

public function myformAjax2($id)
{
    $type = DB::table("room_types")
                ->pluck("price","id");
    return json_encode($type);
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('myform',array('as'=>'myform','uses'=>'InquiriesController@myform'));
Route::get('myform/ajax/{id}',array('as'=>'myform.ajax','uses'=>'InquiriesController@myformAjax'));
Route::get('myform/ajax2/{id}',array('as'=>'myform.ajax2','uses'=>'InquiriesController@myformAjax2'));
Route::get('myform/ajax3/{id}',array('as'=>'myform.ajax3','uses'=>'InquiriesController@myformAjax3'));
```

Comment: Show us your code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

i have use the two dropdown through find the data in dropdown get the ajax through data please try this

```
function get_parts(colorID,select_id)
{
var id = 1;
$('#'+select_id).parent().parent().find('.part_no').html("");
$('#'+select_id).parent().parent().find('.ltr').val("");

var company_id = $("#brand_name option:selected").val();
$.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:'{{url("order/part_view")}}',
        data:'color_id='+colorID+'&company_id='+company_id,
        success:function(html){
            for(var i=0;i<html.length;i++)
            {                
                if(html[i]['id'] == colorID)    
                    var options = "<option value='"+html[i]["part_no"]+"' selected>"+html[i]["part_no"]+"</option>";
                else
                    var options = "<option value='"+html[i]["part_no"]+"'>"+html[i]["part_no"]+"</option>";

                    //var ltr_options = "<option value='"+html[i]["ltr"]+"'>"+html[i]["ltr"]+"</option>";

               $('#'+select_id).parent().parent().find('.part_no').append(options);
               //$('#'+select_id).parent().parent().find('.ltr').append(ltr_options);
               $('#'+select_id).parent().parent().find('.ltr').val(html[0]["ltr"]);
            }
            id++;
        }
});
```

}